# All bash commands hang (out of disk space?!?)

Tags: terminal, disk-space

I know that when I completely run out of space, bash commands in Iterm (and other places) hangs(do not return). Commands such as `ls` and so on. And of course also `df -h`. And if I try to delete a file, it says `no space left in device`. In this case, I need to restart.

Recently, a similar behavior occurred: bash command stopped working.
I was able to delete a small file using Finder(100 mb). Immediately following this, bash command resumed.  I checked free space. Got 24 gb free.

Any explanasion? High Sierra is the OS.

Comment: When you had this happen before, did you then sort out some more storage and move some data to another medium? I work on keeping a minimum of 25 to 40% of the drive free. This allows for updates etc.

Comment: Yes I did get to a situation of 50/70 gb free , and it went back. Can't do better than this.